# How Could I Change The State When Scroll on ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs

I want to change the state when scrolling. Here, the default value of the background is false. I want when scroll the page the value will be true and then I will change the className dynamically using the ternary operator. But it isn't working. please give me a solution using onScoll method and the background state will be changed when scroll the page.

```
const Header = () => {

    const [background, setBackground] = useState(false)




    return (
        <div onScroll={() => setBackground(true)} >
            <div >
   
                <div className={background ?
                 'nav bg-error w-[90%] py-5 mx-auto text-[white] flex justify-between ' 
                :
                 'nav w-[90%]  py-5 mx-auto text-[white] flex justify-between'}>
                    <div>
                        <p> logo</p>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <ul className='flex justify-around'>
                            <li>item1</li>
                            <li className='mx-10'>item2</li>
                            <li className='mr-10'>item3</li>
                            <li>item4</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
                

            </div>
            <div className=' text-[white]'>
                <img src="https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/close-up-islamic-new-year-concept_23-2148611670.jpg?w=1380&t=st=1655822165~exp=1655822765~hmac=c5954765a3375adc1b56f2896de7ea8a604cd1fb725e53770c7ecd8a05821a60" alt="" />
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Header;
```

Answer (score 2):

That's because you need to set `overflow:scroll` to the div. Otherwise the onScroll prop won't work.

But remember that using the solution above will render unwanted extra scrollbars.
So you can try this instead:

```
  const [background, setBackground] = React.useState(false);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("scroll", (e) => setBackground(true));

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("scroll", (e) => setBackground(false));
    };
  }, [background]);
```